# Firebase cloud functions custom domain

Tags: firebase, dns, google-cloud-functions

How do I connect firebase's new HTTPS cloud functions to a custom domain?

So, for example, "example.com/" will go to "us-central1-MY-EXAMPLE.cloudfunctions.net/"

Comment: Too broad and/or unspecific to be answerable. See [help/dont-ask].

Comment: What you are trying to do has been addressed in this blog.  For this solution (not an official solution), you will need to set up a reverse proxy: http://abe.ghost.io/using-a-custom-domain-with-google-cloud-functions-for-firebase/

Comment: Solved! (kinda) https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions you can now use redirects to connect firebase hosting with firebase functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not currently a feature of Cloud Functions for Firebase. But it sounds like an interesting idea, so I'd definitely [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).