# Use custom domain for firebase function http calls

Tags: firebase, dns, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to use a custom domain for firebase cloud functions http hooks.

The default url for cloud functions looks something like this:

`https://us-central1-my-awesome-app.cloudfunctions.net/ios-oauth/`

And

I would like to make it look like this:

`https://myawesomeapp.com/ios-oauth/`

I looked around if there was some other people looking for the same solution and sure enough I found this:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482224/firebase-cloud-functions-custom-domain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482224/firebase-cloud-functions-custom-domain)

Comment: Oct 1 2020, Firebase 7.22.0 was released with "Cloud Functions for Firebase Client SDK: Users can now set a custom domain for callable functions."

Comment: If you are using Express.js with multiple routes, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I have contacted firebase support to get some answers about this.
And I was forwarded to this part in the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site

You can use your own domain with the firebase-cloud-functions. The way to do it is by using the firebase-hosting.

1. Connect custom domain to firebase hosting
2. Add custom function routing to firebase.json

   ```
    {
      "hosting": {
        "public": "public",

        // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
        "rewrites": [{
          "source": "/bigben", "function": "bigben"
        }]

      }
    }
   ```
3. Deploy to firebase

Comment: Would it be possible to create a dynamic route so you didn't have to define each function? Something like `/api/***` where `***` would be the function name? Hope I'm not breaking a rule here, just don't see a reason to create an entire question for this.

Comment: How is this the solution? this is only supported in us-central1.

Comment: [It is January 2021, this solution still works only for `us-central1`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site)

Comment: And it only works for GET requests. If you try a POST, the body is lost...

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer is correct, and I created this repository last year to demonstrate the functionality: https://github.com/cjmyles/firebase-react-express

In order to retain the HTML pushState functionality as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites you may want to extend the rules to allow all other requests through to your index.html page, which solves the issue @Boris was facing in his answer.

```
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
    },
    {
        "source": "!/@(api)/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
```

This shouldn't really be needed as the rewrite rules are meant to match the first occurence of a request (so the order matters), but this worked for me by allowing all non-api related requests through.

**Please note:** At the time of writing this the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function) states: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is great. Might be exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to configure that the `firebase.functions.httpsCallable('myfn')` call using FB JS SDK automatically uses the custom domain instead of the default `https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/`?

Comment: Does the function itself need to be in us-central1 or the hosting? I can't seem to tell based on the documentation.

Comment: @SebastianG No matter where your hosting is located, if the hosting rewrites to a function, then that function MUST be in us-central1.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else runs into this, Thomas Bulva's answer is correct but for me, I also had to remove the below snippet from the firebase.json file.    .

It was redirecting any request to the index.html page. My https://us---<>.cloudfunctions.net URL was working fine;  when I did /helloWorld it would take me to "Hello from Firebase!" But if I tried the same from my custom domain, it would fail. Removing this fixed it.

```
{
   "source": "**",
   "destination": "/index.html"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

### 2024 Update

If anyone is still looking here the rewrites API was changed (as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site)):

```json
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/function1",
    "function": {
      "functionId": "function1"
    }
  },
  {
     "source": "!/@(api)/**",
     "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

I still haven't found a way to reroute **All** functions to the `/api/` as I would like, so at the moment I'm routing them one by one.

As of now (2024) there are 5 regions that support hosting functions:

- us-west1
- us-central1
- us-east1
- europe-west1
- asia-east1

Comment: If all of your API endpoints are sharded out into their own Cloud Functions, wiring them up one-by-one like what you've done here is neccessary. If all of your endpoint are behind one Cloud Function, you would use `"/api{,/**}"` as the source to handle `/api` and any of its children.