# POST to a firebase function behind custom domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We are trying to build a REST api using firebase functions. We want that format because we are a web services company who need to expose an api to our clients. People are mostly familiar with REST, therefore, REST.

Following the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825799/use-custom-domain-for-firebase-function-http-calls) I have layered a custom domain in front of a firebase function. I did this by first forwarding my custom domain to the firebase domain via an A record,then setting up a rewrite for the hosting:

```
  "hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "!/@(api)/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
},
```

Note that the `api` function is mapped to anything going to `/api/`. So far so good. Now I want to make a POST request with a body to `mydomain.com/api/user`. Unfortunately, when doing so, I get a response `Cannot GET /api/user`. It seems like firebase is converting the request into a GET before it reaches the function at `api`. Does anyone know how to make POST requests to functions behind custom domains?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumbles over this it's because our route was not defined as containing `api`. We had something like `/user` but this configuration obviously requires `/api/user`.